# jq 1.5 find nested elements by regex when parent unknown

Tags: regex, bash, jq

Given the JSON structure below i would like to find the first occurrence of object `ccc` so I can add a new object to the children `ddd`. However I do not know the key name of the parent or how many levels deep it may be.

to find

```
"children": {
    "ccc": [{
        "id": "ddd",
        "des": "object d",
        "parent": "ccc"
    }]
}
```

full JSON stored in $myJson

```
{
"zzz": [{
    "id": "aaa",
    "des": "object A",
    "parent": "zzz",
    "children": {
        "aaa": [{
            "id": "bbb",
            "des": "object B",
            "parent": "aaa",
            "children": {
                "bbb": [{
                    "id": "ccc",
                    "des": "object C",
                    "parent": "bbb",
                    "children": {
                        "ccc": [{
                            "id": "ddd",
                            "des": "object d",
                            "parent": "ccc"
                        }]
                    }
                }, {
                    "id": "eee",
                    "des": "object e",
                    "parent": "bbb"
                }]
            }
        },{
            "id": "fff",
            "des": "object f",
            "parent": "aaa"
        }]
    }
}]}
```

follow some other answers I have tried combinations of

```
output=($(jq -r '.. | with_entries(select(.key|match("ccc";"i")))' <<< ${myjson}))
```

or

```
output=($(jq -r '.. | to_entries | map(select(.key | match("ccc";"i"))) | map(.value)' <<< ${myjson}))
```

all give errors of a similar nature `jq: error (at <stdin>:1): number (0) cannot be matched, as it is not a string`

Comment: post the final result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following, I'll assume you want to add "ADDITIONAL" to the array at EVERY key that matches a given regex (here "ccc"):

```
walk(if type == "object"
     then with_entries(if (.key|test("ccc"))
                       then .value += ["ADDITIONAL"] else . end)
     else . end)
```

If your jq does not have `walk/1`, then you can simply copy-and-paste its def from the [jq FAQ](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ) or [builtin.jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ)

#### Alternative formulation

If you have the following general-purpose helper function handy (e.g. in your ~/.jq):

```
def when(filter; action): if (filter?) // null then action else . end;
```

then the above solution shrinks down to:

```
walk(when(type == "object";
     with_entries(when(.key|test("ccc"); .value += ["ADDITIONAL"]))))
```

Comment: thanks @peak, it took me a while to understand how to add the helper function. Your code almost does what I need but it adds the `ADDITIONAL` to `ccc` instead of to all children under `ccc` such as `ddd`

Comment: That’s why it makes sense to follow the guidelines at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve